# Load head of a page in pagehead

Tags: jquery, load, head

Is it posible to load the head of a page in the head of the current page with jQuery? I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  jQuery(function() {
    var page = http://www.mysite.com/mypage;
    jQuery('head').load(page +' head');
  });
```

Comment: Why do you wan to load on head?

Comment: I have a div with a mediaplayer. I want to keep the music playing while I navigate through my site. I can load the sitecontent, but not the head.

Comment: In what way did it not seem to work? Did the head element in the DOM get replaced or not. Did you expect the page to update itself with whatever CSS or JS are specified in the new HEAD? Good luck with that. Actually if I go to http://api.jquery.com/load/ and run $("head").load("http://api.jquery.com head") from the JS console in Firefox, it does seem to mash the page up quite badly, so something is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate through a site mean that you refresh the pages and you will not be able to play a sound without gliches.

Sound on a side is a bad idea, but if you must ... make a frame for the div with the player and a frame for the pages content. It's not a good practice but it will work and it simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the content of the head, but why?!

```
$(function() {
  $('head').html('html');
  $('head title').html('new title');
});
```